# jQuery popup doesn't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, popup

I've tried closing a jQuery iframe popup but I can't seem to be able to. I've seen a lot of solutions to similar problems, but I think something is gravely wrong with my code.

I have this code

```
    <a id="button" href="#popupVideo" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">Ε</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupVideo" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="a" data-tolerance="15,15" class="ui-content">
    <iframe id="iframeId" src="http://localhost:8080/newfile.php","MsgWindow" width="1000" height="600" seamless=""></iframe>
</div>
```

And it does what I want, provides a window with an iframe from a file I have. However, while closing it by clicking outside it in the grayed out area is simple, using a button to close the window somehow is proving really hard to do.

I just want to pretend the button event is similar to clicking outside the window. I also want another button that reloads the iframe (I can currently open a new window inside the iframe, but the previous one stays).

Things like window.close from the iframe's Javascript don't seem to work.

Comment: what plugin are you using for the popup? can you add the jquery that initialises it?

Comment: I just included this

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

No code is necessary other than that to initialize it

I just updated the link to the latest versions. still I cannot figure out how to close the popup

Comment: Can you post your javascript, and/or a fiddle?

Comment: Your putting your javascript in newfile.php right ?

Comment: do you have a link to a sample so i can use dev tools on it

Comment: Yes the javascript is called from the newfile.php
Inside it I have tried a lot of things that don't work. What's the proper way of signalling a "close popup" event when someone clicks a button? The only code that currently exists after deleting,copying pasting and trying things, is some nonfunctional jquery code. I just need the proper way to do it, when the code is just the above. 

I'll put it inside a javascript file called by newfile.php and see if it works (the function will be called by the button)